# Matlab (State-space model) gives this error

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab 2020a

I run this simple Matlab code example from Matlab help:

```
A = [-1.5,-2;1,0];
B = [0.5;0];
C = [0,1];
D = 0;
sys = ss(A,B,C,D);
```

It gives this error:

> Error using ss
> If a class defines superclasses, all or none must be handle classes.

> Error in Untitled (line 5)
> sys = ss(A,B,C,D);

This code was run in Matlab 2018a, now is not run in Matlab 2020a

Comment: _"I am using Matlab 2020a"_ | _"This code was run in Matlab 2018a"_. Which is it? Or does it complain in both versions?

Comment: what does `help ss` return in your case? It's possible that you have defined a class called `ss` which is included in your search path.

Answer (score 0):

You should put D In Parentheses and then you can run your code easily as follows to derive continuous time transfer function and state space of the model :

```
A = [-1.5,-2;1,0];
B = [0.5;0];
C = [0,1];
D = [0];
sys = ss(A,B,C,D);
Transfer_Function = tf(sys)
```

Comment: I'm using exactly this code and it's working for me.maybe in your code You have defined a parameter called "ss" and it does not working.Otherwise you should see the help of "ss" function in matlab.my matlab version is 2013 Ra.

Comment: This code was run in Matlab 2018a, now is not run in Matlab 2020a